Does the loading of an RS485 transceiver depend on the length of the cable used?
I am testing the performance of an RS485 port in a device using a 1km long cable.
My doubt is, does the length of the cable have any impact on the overall loading (current consumption) of the device as a whole?
Will the loading of the device while using a 1km long cable be the same as if I use, for eg, a 10m cable?

Simple answer. Never.   Where are your results for jitter, baudrate vs length, pF/m, Zo and group delay

What are your cable specs (link?) and test criteria?

I'm assuming you are parallel terminating the cable at the destination, with ~100 ohms?  Then the DC loading will be less because of the resistance of the cable, which is in series with the terminating resistor.
You said 1 km of cable.  24 gauge wire has a resistance of ~26 ohms/1,000 ft.  For your 1 km example, this is translates to 3.2 times that, or 83.2 ohms (one way).  Two way resistance wold then be 2X that or 166.4 ohms.
So the cable resistance, along with the parallel terminations would give you a total resistance of 266.2 ohms, which would reduce the DC loading, & current, on the interface.
From an AC standpoint, you are going to see the edge rate decrease as you go down the cable.  This is because of dielectric effects, which cause the high frequency part of the edges to be attenuated along the cable.

AWG 26 is also common at 39.7 Ohms /1kft or 132 Ohms/km resistance. What BW would you expect at 1km? for -3dB? -20 dB biphase?


Will the loading of (an RS-485) device while using a 1km long cable be the same as if I use, for eg, a 10m cable?"

The short answer is no.    How will you test the step response and symbol rate vs distance?
The long answer is the cable properties & length affect slew rate, attenuation, jitter, +/-60 mA current driver, Tx impedance 20 ohms and Rx sensitivity of 200 mV with 50 mV hysteresis.
The cable properties from the Heaviside Effect are dominated by driver current, source Rs, cable capacitance and resistance, thus a 1st-order RC approximation for data rate vs distance. the 100 kbps knee represents a square wave of 50 kHz or a symbol period of 10 us.
Compute the \$T_{delay}=\sqrt{LC}\$ of 4000 ft = 1219 m.
Analog Devices shows this conservative guide and "fail-safe" termination method:
 Source: Analog Devices
Compute current demand based on cable capacitance and frequency:
This is a level 1 approximation.
\$f_{max}= \dfrac{I_{driver}}{C_{total}⋅V}\$
This plot show a flat response to 1219 m = 4000 ft
What pf/m assumption was used?  Let's convert to pF/m.\$10^{-12}F\$ using
\${C_{pF/m} = \dfrac{I_{driver}} {f⋅V}\$
  Source: Analog Devices
Telegrapher's Equation defines cable impedance with a lumped element equivalent that has R(f), and L(f) variables due to skin effect and delay  
\$Z_0 = \frac{\sqrt{R+ jωL}}{\sqrt{G+jωC}}\$
For extremely long cables Oliver Heaviside improved upon Telegrapher's Equation for Transmission lines with the "Heaviside Condition" to eliminate cable dispersion with phase velocity being higher than group velocity.
\$\frac{G}{C}=\frac{R}{L}\$
  What Heaviside proved here without stating it is that to eliminate the frequency-dependent dispersion the Electric and Magnetic energies must be equal to generate an optimal digital signal but is does not exist as the conductor
This affects the eye pattern jitter in synchronous data, especially when the bandwidth spans decades of frequency. Heaviside solved this problem in the trans-Atlantic subterranean telegraph cable of very slow Morse Code using an iron-alloy conductor to raise the cable inductance in shield cable under the Atlantic with Dk=80 for water just so they could reach 1/15s baud rate. This was about 150 years ago and allowed stock prices to be shared between London and Wall Street long before "eye pattern" was even a thing.  It looked more like ocean waves.
Anecdote
If you ever are confronted with group delay distortion in eye patterns, just remember to use "Raised Cosine" Filters to solve the InterSymbol Interference(ISI). I learned this in 1979 when we were inventing 1.544 Megabaud (T1/DS1) modems using the midband for distribution and sub-band 6MHz/12MHz carrier for the sub. This was the world's 1st CATV broadband ISDN/WAN to 100 homes called Project Ida. Other uses of Raised Cosine filters were used for 4 MBaud NRZ on a TV channel using the unused blanked video lines in '82. My employer was called Interdiscom System Ltd (ISL) in Winnipeg.

Current is limited by RS-485 drivers and recommended by TI is +/-60 mA with +/-80 mA can be possible.  The receiver Zin = 12 kΩ(min), with an input sensitivity of ±200 mV, and a typical input hysteresis of 50 mV.

TI offers many RS-485 & RS-422 products


Cable Resistance Ω/1000ft or Ω/km wire vs. diameter or AWG of conductor and metal (Cu, Ni, Sn, Fe, Ag)

Cable capacitance is dependent on the dielectric constant, Dk of both the differential pair and if shielded the paired wires to shield for common mode.

e.g. low C twisted pair 13.5 pF/ft (44 pF/m) vs older PVC cable 40 pF/ft 131 pF/m)


https://www.quabbin.com/sites/default/files/files/Why-is-Cable-Capacitance-Important-for-Electronic-Applications.pdf
     Quabbin Wire & Cable Co.   
     P/N Construction OD Mutual Capacitance 
     2210 4 pair 24 AWG no shield Category 6 .220" 13.5 pf/ft
     8508 4 pair 24 AWG O/A shield (RS232) .277" 13 pf/ft
     9508 4 pair 28 AWG O/A shield (RS422) .233" 15.5 pf/ft
     9720 2 pair 22 AWG pairs shielded DS-1 oval 15.0 pf/ft

https://www.quabbin.com
Renesas states this in 2023:
  "Essentially, the driver output is a waveform that combines both positive and negative 
      differential voltages on top of a common-mode offset voltage,  
      which usually amounts to half of the supply voltage (VCC/2). 
   According to the RS-485 standard, the driver must be able to produce a 
     differential output voltage of more than 1.5V across a 54Ω load. 
   To achieve this, the on-resistance of both high-side and low-side transistors is kept low, 
     typically between 20Ω and 30Ω, to supply enough current for this voltage level. 
   The standard also requires the driver to maintain this output voltage with  
     a 60Ω differential load and a common-mode load of 375Ω, accommodating a range from -7V to +12V"
   ( even if the cable Zo is 100 or 120 ohms the RS-485 std.)  D.A.S. added  


Microchip specifies: Due to cable tolerances and choice of termination the  Reflected Attenuation Factor (RAF) = -15 dB. This means Return loss or s11=15 dB min. This affects the transition ringing level [dB].

For those who like math, here are some heavy ;) equations. The key is to solve the Heaviside equations with 1st and 2nd derivatives.
Here's a test process, using low-C twisted pair:
Define typical properties for:
R=0.1 Ω/m   L=0.4 μH/m  
C=50 pF/m   G=0.01 S/m 

Analyze signal propagation across a range of frequencies (e.g., 1 MHz to 1 GHz).
Compute:
1. Attenuation vs. Frequency
2. Group Delay vs. Frequency
3. Bandwidth as a function of distance

\$γ=\sqrt{(R+jωL)(G+jωC)}\$
​\$Z_0=\sqrt{\dfrac{R+jωL}{G+jωC}}\$​
​\$Attenuation (dB/100m) = 20⋅log10​(e)⋅Re(γ)⋅100\$
γ:  transmission line propagation constant
Zo: characteristic impedance (Ω)
L:  Inductance per unit length (H/m)
G:  Conductance per unit length (S/m)
C: Capacitance per unit length (F/m)
ω=2πf: Angular frequency (rad/s)     

\$τ_g​ = Group Delay =  −\dfrac{dPhase(γ)}{dω}\$​
Bandwidth*distance product vs Capacitance [MHz-km vs. pF] uses attenuation using +/-60 mA and sensitivity threshold with many calculations.


This calculation requires verification.
More info:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ta/ssztcl5/ssztcl5.pdf


Interesting note on the data rate vs cable length graph that came from Analog Devices.  As I think I've pointed out in other questions, that graph was empirically derived for RS-422 and first appeared in ANSI/TIA/EIA-422- in the early 70s (maybe even before that). It shows up in my 1977 AMD S/LS Data Book.  Many companies today, Analog Devices, TI, NSC, just republish it without acknowledgement as to its origins.

@SteveSh noted, so I computed more details.


Will the loading of the device while using a 1km long cable be the same as if I use, for eg, a 10m cable?

to a first approximation it will be the same load,  the characteristic impedance of a cable is an expression that is independent of cable length,
If you use a 120 ohm cable and terminate the ends with 120 ohm resistors  the capacitance and self-inductance of the cable cancel out.
In the real world you also have dielectric absorbtion, to deal with.
and the fact that the dielectric is a much better insulator than the copper is a conductor.  from this the impedance of the cable gets some frequency dependent perturbations, and the signal gets smeared out, still a kilometer cable isn't going to overload your driver, but it will distort and attenuate the signal some by the time it reaches the receive end.
With all this on a long cable the load presented to the transmitter will be less at DC because of the copper resistance, and even less at higher frequencies because of skin effect. However because of the distortion you may not get a useful signal at the end. reducing the frequency (baud rate) will lessen the amount of distortion.

you are making assumptions but not stating them in your argument. e.g.  Rise time, dispersion, skin effect (f) , group delay distortion (f) , baud rate .

I think this answer is also saying that to the first approximation, there is no stray capacitance between data wires and ground, so a 1000m wire loads the chip just as much than a 1m wire and chip supply/ground currents are equal into the perfect or lossy transmission line. Please note that cables do specify that there is capacitance imbalance allowed between wire A to ground and B to ground. And driver CM imbalance allowed when driving the cable. These capacitances do get charged and discharged.

A cable has capacitance per unit length described in data sheet.
A 1000 meter cable has 100 times the capacitance of 10 meter cable.
Charging the wire capacitance does provide additional load that increases driver current.
Edit: For those who downvote, please read the "Capacitive Effects" on this SMSC Technical Note 7-5 on RS-485, and then provide an argument why the Technical Note would be incorrect and capacitance does not matter.
tn75.pdf

This assumes the cable looks like a lumped load to the driver, which is does not.  It's still a transmission line.

While the parallel capacitance is 1000x higher, so is the series inductance. Since the two oppose each other and increase in lockstep with length you get the usual transmission line result that (ignoring resistance) the load does not depend on length for a terminated line.

I agree with Justme in that pF/m has a significant on kBaud-km product. Low capacitance cable for 1 km would have to be compared with transition rates. Those who are not familiar with the constants for Mbaud-meter product on data cables need to learn that the attenuation factor is significantly controlled by cable capacitance, this then upvote Justme's answer  or justify their comments negate his true statements  +1  Although he could have included Heaviside's equations were better than Telegrapher's to compute this dB/100m sensitivity from C. Causes can be complex and nonlinear/ skin-effects

I agree that pF/m (capacitance per unit length) does affect things like achievable data rate.  But Justme said a "1000 meter cable has 100 times the capacitance of 10 meter cable", not 100 times the capacitance per unit length.  But OP's question was about DC loading on the bus, which is in no way affected by capacitance, either total or per unit length.

@SteveSh There is no implication about DC loading, just loading. The transmission line is not a perfect resistance at characteristic impedance, as in addition to unit capacitance, the data wires have capacitance to shield. Even if high frequencies experience a transmission line, the interface is DC coupled and any imbalance in the common mode transmission is affected by capacitance from data wires to shield. It takes about 5 microseconds for signal to travel the 1km. If this was not an issue, the cable makers would not need to manufacture, sell, or market low capacitance data cables.

@Steveh I believe you may have assumed 2 contradictions to facts. It was never stated as 100 times the capacitance per unit length so assuming the same cable type, his statement is true. Secondly, the current limit is not due to DC which was never assumed nor stated. Rather Ic=V/R+CdV/dt using TI's recommended +/-60 mA

I think you're reading a lot more into the question than what was there.  Lacking anything about data rates or duty cycle (there wasn't anything about those in the question), it doesn't make any sense to talk about AC effects. like C*(dV/dt).  I assumed a simple, static case, which I think is what OP was asking.

@SteveSh I assumed that the data bus performance testing was used to actually send data, instead of static DC case. Sure, the DC case is also important, but usually, bus loading means both AC and DC.

@Justme - I agree, partly.  What you said is true, but without knowing things like data rates, it's impossible to assess the dynamic power draw; to quantify it.  Maybe a simulation or analysis of power/current vs data rate would be useful.

@SteveSh  You are repeating contradictory opinions and not quoting facts. The 120 ohm terminator with pull-up/down bias resistors using "Fail-safe" method only draws  3 to 5 mA DC.
